# How do I measure the accuracy of a LSTM regression model for a timeseries?

Tags: time-series, lstm

Given the stochastic nature of the model, it will produce different results for RMSE, MAPE etc each time you run it. Do I just build the model n times and I get the average of the metrics?

Comment: Why not set a seed so you can have a model that you assert is your model?

Comment: what is a seed?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed

Comment: Briefly, a seed sets what the randomness will be for a given session. That is, if I run `np.random.seed(2021)` and then `np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)`, I will get the same ten values every time I run those lines. In your case, if you set a seed (and train the same number of epochs), your model will converge to the same value every time, giving you "the" model. (If you alter the number of training epochs or other parameters (e.g., batch size), you will alter the convergence.)

Comment: got it thank you

Answer (score 2):

Since your LSTM is stochastic, there is no "the" accuracy. One possibility is to train it multiple times and average the resulting accuracies (which estimated the *expected* accuracy). An alternative, as Dave comments, is to set an RNG seed, so your LSTM is not stochastic any more, and then you indeed can report "the" accuracy.

Comment: (Let's set aside our usual gripes about accuracy.) I would argue that, if I can get an out-of-sample accuracy of $95\%$ from one training of the model and only $91\%$ from another training, the second training is bogus. I would pick the parameter estimates from the first model and ignore the ones from the second.

Comment: @Dave: I do see your point. One problem I see here is: what's to keep us from overfitting to the validation set? We could rerun the training many times with different seeds, but at some point, we are overfitting. After all, when we choose training A over training B based on the accuracies on the validation set, the validation set starts being part of the training.